# Amazon AWS EC2 always returns empty response?

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to run Django on an Apache server in an EC2 instance on AWS. As just a test (I know not to use the Django dev server in production) I used `manage.py` to run the Django dev server with: `python manage.py 0.0.0.0:8000`. Whenever I try to connect to the EC2 instance via its public IP on port 8000, I get an `err_empty_response` from Chrome.

I spent hours playing with an Apache config to try to get the full-on Django production server set up to work as well, but no luck. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Probably al incoming traffic is blocked by the firewall?

Comment: The security group my instance is a part of allows HTTP traffic over port 80 from `0.0.0.0/0` (note that I changed to the command `python manage.py 0.0.0.0:80` to access the server over port 80). I believe this is correct as seen [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/GettingStartedGuide/getting-started-create-security-group.html). It also always changes the url to place `https://` in front, despite the fact that I don't want to require https.  @rfkortekaas Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: 1) Check your security group 2) find default web server is running based on your Linux flavour 3) ping your ec2 Dns address and chk response 4) if you use elb chk port 80 is mapped to listening port

Comment: Add Security rule TCP 8000 0.0.0.0/0 and then check

Comment: What happens when you run `curl http://localhost:8000/` on the instance itself?  Firewall issues wouldn't normally cause an empty response.  Chrome would complain about being unable to connect.

Comment: ini the question you are saying port 8000 in the comment it's 80? which is it? Please update your question